# How to fix this scoring?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on a game, and I want it to count each time something is added to the screen. I have set up `NSMutableArrays` to contain the content I add to the screen. There are 6 arrays, and each of them spawns an item every x amount of seconds. This is what I've set up for scoring:

```
if (!_scoreLabel) {
    _scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"DIN Condensed"];
    _scoreLabel.fontSize = 40;
    _scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width - 20, self.frame.size.height - 40);
    _scoreLabel.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:1 alpha:0.5];
    _scoreLabel.zPosition = 2.0;
    [self addChild:_scoreLabel];
}

//add each debris array
_scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _debris.count + _debris2.count + _debris3.count + _debris4.count + _debris5.count + _debris6.count];
```

This code works fine for the first little while of playing the game (from `_debris1` - `_debris3`) then when `debris4` and others start spawning, the scoring doesn't properly add 1 by 1. Instead it starts to add clumps of score, (if thats confusing: for the first part of the game, it adds 1 every time a piece of debris is added to the game, then when 4 and others come, it starts to add 3, 7, 3, (random amounts), of score to the `_scoreLabel`.

Is there any reason as to why this is doing this? **Is it possible to have an `NSMutabaleArray` contain all of these arrays as children?** Should I be calculating this score differently?

This is a sample `spawnDebris` method if needed:

```
-(void)spawnDebris {

    SKSpriteNode * debris = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"debris1.png"] size:CGSizeMake(70, 70)];
    debris.zPosition = 1.0;

    debris.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:30];
    debris.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    debris.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionDebris;

    RandomPosition = arc4random() %300;
    RandomPosition = RandomPosition + 20;
    debris.position = CGPointMake (RandomPosition, self.size.height + 40);

    [_debris addObject:debris]; //_debris is the NSMutableArray 
    [self addChild:debris];

    //next Spawn:
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction waitForDuration:deb1Time],
        [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnDebris) onTarget:self],
    ]]];

    if (_dead == YES) {
        [self removeAllActions];
    }

    if (debris.position.y > 568) {
        [self removeFromParent];
    }
```

Thanks in advanced. **Please let me know if there is any other information required.**

Comment: What about simply changing the scoring from 1 to a a higher number like 3 or something so the user can't tell when it's randomly changing?

Comment: It goes by array count @ShenHutah

Comment: About the last if statement: shouldn't that be [debris removeFromParent]; instead of [self removeFromParent]; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies in your code logic. Your spawnDebris method calls itself recursively every deb1Time seconds which makes it independent. If your other debris methods operate in the same way then you have no real control over when things happen. The solution is to include a [self updateScore] into your debris methods to update the score whenever a change is made.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Happy coding!